# função densidade de probabilidade em python

Tags: python, scipy

Eu não consigo criar uma função densidade de probabilidade contínua para uma variável aleatória para plotar ela sobre o histograma.

```
val = df[['posição', 'num']].groupby('num').agg(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index()
cont = 0
fprob=[]
for i in val.index:
    cont += len(val.query('index=={}'.format(i))
    fprob.append(len(val.query('index=={}'.format(i))/(cont*(len(df)/len(var)))
```

Foi isso que eu tentei, onde o val guarda as posições em que o valor num se repete dentro de df. Dai eu tentei buscar para cada valor quantas vezes ele se repete e dividir isso pela quantidade de valores que já foram testados vezes a proporção que cada valor representa do df. Não conheço nenhuma função que já me forneça a função densidade de probabilidade, por isso tentei assim.

Comment: qualquer função de densidade tem forma funcional definida. Qual função vc deseja? Normal, poisson, binomial?

Comment: Então, é a partir de um dataframe com uma distribuição que eu n sei qual é a forma